# Multidimensional use of .map() array function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, material-ui

I'm currently stuck in trying to transform one array to another using an array of headers as a key variable. Somewhat confusing to explain so I think the code might be better.

// Array received from backend

```
const projects = [
  {id: 0001, name: "Test Project 1", projectType: "Quant"},
  {id: 0002, name: "Test Project 2", projectType: "Qual"},
  {id: 0003, name: "Test Project 3", projectType: "Quant"},
];
```

I use the first object of the array to create a new array for the headers using Object.keys(projects[0]).. So far so good

I would like to use the DataGrid from Material UI which requires a specific format for their rows and columns data structures. See below.

```
const columns-MUI = [
  {
    field: 'firstName',
    headerName: 'First name',
    width: 150,
    editable: true,
  },
  {
    field: 'lastName',
    headerName: 'Last name',
    width: 150,
    editable: true,
  },
];

const rows-MUI = [
  { id: 1, lastName: 'Snow', firstName: 'Jon', age: 35 },
  { id: 2, lastName: 'Lannister', firstName: 'Cersei', age: 42 },
  { id: 3, lastName: 'Lannister', firstName: 'Jaime', age: 45 },
  { id: 4, lastName: 'Stark', firstName: 'Arya', age: 16 },
]
```

I've managed to convert the headers from the result of Object.keys(projects[0]) to the desired column structure as defined by in columns-MUI with the following code when setting the state in a useEffect hook:

```
setNewColumns(tableHeaders?.map(( header, index ) => {
  return { 
    field: index,
    headerName: header,
    width: 90
  }
}));
```

Where I'm stuck is transforming the array from projects to rows-MUI because I somehow need to create both the key and value pair dynamically. This is what I've resulted in so far:

```
let tempProjectsList = [];
projectsList?.map(( project, index) => {
  let projectObject = ''  
  tableHeaders.map(( header, index ) => {
      const value = project[header] != null ? `"${project[header]}"` : ""
      projectObject += `${header}:${value},`;
    })
  const parsedObject =`{${projectObject}}`;
  tempProjectsList.push(parsedObject); 
})
```

This process treats the key value pair as a string and parses the object once the iteration through the tableHeaders array is complete. There must be a more elegant solution though that I'm missing so I'd much appreciate the help.

I am certain that the "more elegant" solution begins like this but I think I reach the limits of my knowledge of Javascript arrays at this point:

```
setNewRows(projectsList?.map(( project, index) => {
  return tableHeaders.map(( header, index) => {
    
  })
}));
```

Let me know if this explanation isn't clear and I'll work on supplying demo of some description.

Comment: There isn’t much difference between the structure of `projects` and that of `rows-mui` - are you sure it needs to be transformed?  If so, can you give an example of what the transformed output should be?

Comment: Hi James, you're completed right. It must have been too late and thus didn't occur to me that the projectsList structure already has the format that I need. The problem I found was in the restructuring of the columns array. As a field I used index and this should have been header. In any case, thanks for taking the time to read my post!